# Woocommerce order cancellation redirect from email

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

I am looking to extend our order cancellation links with a redirect to our accounts dashboard from the Admin New Order email notification (emails > admin-new-order.php).

Currently I have set this up like this with the customised admin-new-order.php notification

```
$cancel_url = $order->get_cancel_order_url_raw();
echo wp_kses_post( sprintf( __( 'Your ride will only be secured once you have finalised the payment.<br> <br> %s', 'woocommerce-bookings' ), '<a href="' . $cancel_url . '">Cancel my booking</a>' ) );
```

Currently when the cancellation link is triggered the order is cancelled however it is redirecting back to our home page. I would like this to redirect to the account page instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should achieve what you’re after:

```
$redirect_url = get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('myaccount'));
$cancel_url = $order->get_cancel_order_url_raw($redirect_url);
```

**Reference**:
https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Order.html#method_get_cancel_order_url_raw

Comment: I am encountering another issue and cannot figure it out. The generated url outputs   `https://mysite.cloud/cart/?cancel_order=true&order=wc_order_yhVDsd8LFwTk0&order_id=7640&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.cloud%2Faccount%2Fbookings&_wpnonce=e949aa05d417` However the order is not cancelling when the order status is 'Pending Payment'. I am being redirected to my shop archive page.